# styling of pandas dataframe

Tags: dataframe, numpy, pandas-styles

I have a data frame with multiple columns:

main dataframe

```
        CPU(%)  CPU_User(%)  CPU_System(%)  CPU_IO(%)
fa_ha    52.66        45.16           7.68       7.14
fa_pri   93.18        79.46          15.26       7.87
opt3     69.70        60.19           7.37       2.20
```

Now i need to apply styling to this dataframe but styling depends on thresholds and each column will have different thresholds , for ex:

threshold dataframe:

```
       CPU(%)  CPU_User(%)  CPU_System(%)  CPU_IO(%)
Lower      65            5             20         40
Upper      95           10             30         50
```

i need to apply styling based on thresholds and make the cell to be(green) if the value in cell is lower than lower threshold for particular column , yellow if it is between the thresholds and red if it is above hupper threshold

EX: CPU(%) value 52.66 should be green as it is less than lower threshold of CPU(%) 65.

```
def bounded_highlights(testdf):
    conds = [testdf > threshold_df.loc['Upper'] ,testdf < threshold_df.loc['Lower']]
    print(conds)
    labels = ['color:red','color: green']
    return np.select(conds, labels, default='')
```

```
styler_object2=maindf.apply(bounded_highlights,axis=None)
```

but got error

```
    raise ValueError(f"No axis named {axis} for object type {cls.__name__}")
ValueError: No axis named None for object type DataFrame
```

also tried :

```
styler_object2=maindf.apply(bounded_highlights)
```

```
    raise ValueError("Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects")
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine, but you need to use [`style.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html):

```
def bounded_highlights(testdf):
    conds = [testdf > threshold_df.loc['Upper'] ,testdf < threshold_df.loc['Lower']]
    print(conds)
    labels = ['color:red','color: green']
    return np.select(conds, labels, default='color: purple')

maindf.style.apply(bounded_highlights,axis=None)
```

*NB. adding a purple color with in between bounds.*

[image]

Comment: thankyou so much i missed that style.apply and trying to debug this since 1 hour

Comment: @nsrsairajesh glad it helped! I hate to debug and then realize I was looking at the wrong thing ;)